# Trouble with straight forward differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is first to find $y(t)$ from the differential equation:
$y'=(1/3)y(6-y);  y(0)=3.$

I changed this to be
$y'=-(1/3)y(y-6)$.

Separating the variables I get
$-3dy/((y)(y-6))=1 dt$.

I solved this left hand integral via partial fractions and got
$-3=A/y + B/(y-6)$,

and solving for $A$ and $B$ I got $A=1/2$ and $B=-1/2$.

This gave me $1/2 \ln|y|-1/2 \ln|y-6|=t+C$.

This simplifies to $\ln((y)/(y-6))=t+C$.  $C=0$ with the initial condition.

Solving this for $y$ I get: $y=6e^{2t}/(e^{2t}-1)$.

Wolfram gets the demoninator to be $e^{2t}+1$.

Have worked this so many times but can't get Wolfram's answer.
Do you see my error?

Answer (score 1):

I think your error was going from $|y-6|$ to $y-6$.

Note that $y(0)=3$, so, at least when $t=0$, $y-6<0$.

If you replace $|y-6|$ with $6-y$, I think you'll see that plus sign in the final answer.

Also, I note it should be $\color{red}{\frac12}\ln(y/(6-y))=t+C$.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:
$$ \ln|y|- \ln|y-6|=2t+C$$

### $$\dfrac {y}{y-6}=ce^{2t}$$

I got this:
$$y=\dfrac {6ce^{2t}}{ce^{2t}-1}$$
With $y(0)=3 \implies c=-1$ it gives WA's answer:
$$y=\dfrac {6e^{2t}}{e^{2t}+1}$$

Comment: This is interesting!  If I find C when the equation is still in natural log form, I get C=0!!!  Why is that????

Comment: I would get ln|3|-ln|3-6|=C

Comment: and that would yield $C=0$

Comment: Yeah thats the difference ...You plug the inital condition before to get the final answer. But when I pluged the initial condition after I got the final answer. I got WA answer @user163862 I think you have to take the absolute value for $y-6$ since it's less than zero

Comment: yes, I see you have the correct answer and I totally see it now.  However, I would think you should be able to find C at any point in the equation....No?

Comment: True but your log is negative ( you get $\ln |-1|$  ...so you have to take the log as  $y/(6-y)$ and everything works fine.... @user163862

Comment: To avoid all these complications with absolute value it's better to wait till you get the final answer for y then apply initial condition....@user163862

Comment: doesn't the absolute value of my log make it be $ln|3-6|=ln |-3|=ln|3| which makes c=0?$

Comment: I meant $\ln (y/(y-6))$ is negative @user

Comment: And around your initial condition $y-6 <0$ so $ \ln (y-6)=6-y$ @user163862

Answer (score 0):

You should have

$$\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{6-y}=\frac 13$$

with $$A=\frac 16$$
and
$$B=A$$
we check that

$$\frac{1}{6y}+\frac{1}{6(6-y)}=\frac{1}{y(6-y)}$$

thus

$$\ln(C\frac{y}{6-y})=2t$$

and

$$Cy=(6-y)e^{2t}$$
or

$$y(t)=\frac{6e^{2t}}{C+e^{2t}}$$
the condition $y(0)=3$ gives $C=1$.

Comment: Using the initial conditions, C=-1, so this gives my answer, not the answer given by Woflram.

Comment: @user163862 You made a mistake in the seventh line. it is -1/3 instead of -3.